# Performance decrease with function call

Tags: optimization, go, slice

For the following function:

```
func CycleClock(c *ballclock.Clock) int {
    for i := 0; i < fiveMinutesPerDay; i++ {
        c.TickFive()
    }

    return 1 + CalculateBallCycle(append([]int{}, c.BallQueue...))
}
```

where `c.BallQueue` is defined as `[]int` and `CalculateBallCycle` is defined as `func CalculateBallCycle(s []int) int`. I am having a huge performance decrease between the `for` loop and the `return` statement.

I wrote the following benchmarks to test. The first benchmarks the entire function, the second benchmarks the `for` loop, while the third benchmarks the `CalculateBallCycle` function:

```
func BenchmarkCycleClock(b *testing.B) {
    for i := ballclock.MinBalls; i <= ballclock.MaxBalls; i++ {
        j := i
        b.Run("BallCount="+strconv.Itoa(i), func(b *testing.B) {
            for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
                c, _ := ballclock.NewClock(j)

                CycleClock(c)
            }
        })
    }
}

func BenchmarkCycle24(b *testing.B) {
    for i := ballclock.MinBalls; i <= ballclock.MaxBalls; i++ {
        j := i
        b.Run("BallCount="+strconv.Itoa(i), func(b *testing.B) {
            for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
                c, _ := ballclock.NewClock(j)

                for k := 0; k < fiveMinutesPerDay; k++ {
                    c.TickFive()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

func BenchmarkCalculateBallCycle123(b *testing.B) {
    m := []int{8, 62, 42, 87, 108, 35, 17, 6, 22, 75, 116, 112, 39, 119, 52, 60, 30, 88, 56, 36, 38, 26, 51, 31, 55, 120, 33, 99, 111, 24, 45, 21, 23, 34, 43, 41, 67, 65, 66, 85, 82, 89, 9, 25, 109, 47, 40, 0, 83, 46, 73, 13, 12, 63, 15, 90, 121, 2, 69, 53, 28, 72, 97, 3, 4, 94, 106, 61, 96, 18, 80, 74, 44, 84, 107, 98, 93, 103, 5, 91, 32, 76, 20, 68, 81, 95, 29, 27, 86, 104, 7, 64, 113, 78, 105, 58, 118, 117, 50, 70, 10, 101, 110, 19, 1, 115, 102, 71, 79, 57, 77, 122, 48, 114, 54, 37, 59, 49, 100, 11, 14, 92, 16}

    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        CalculateBallCycle(m)
    }
}
```

Using 123 balls, this gives the following result:

```
BenchmarkCycleClock/BallCount=123-8                  200           9254136 ns/op
BenchmarkCycle24/BallCount=123-8                  200000              7610 ns/op
BenchmarkCalculateBallCycle123-8                 3000000               456 ns/op
```

Looking at this, there is a huge disparity between benchmarks. I would expect that the first benchmark would take roughly `~8000 ns/op` since that would be the sum of the parts.

[Here](https://github.com/Nais777/BallClock-golang.git) is the github repository.

EDIT:

I discovered that the result from the benchmark and the result from the running program are widely different. I took what @yazgazan found and modified the benchmark function in `main.go` mimic somewhat the `BenchmarkCalculateBallCycle123` from `main_test.go`:

```
func Benchmark() {
    for i := ballclock.MinBalls; i <= ballclock.MaxBalls; i++ {
        if i != 123 {
            continue
        }

        start := time.Now()

        t := CalculateBallCycle([]int{8, 62, 42, 87, 108, 35, 17, 6, 22, 75, 116, 112, 39, 119, 52, 60, 30, 88, 56, 36, 38, 26, 51, 31, 55, 120, 33, 99, 111, 24, 45, 21, 23, 34, 43, 41, 67, 65, 66, 85, 82, 89, 9, 25, 109, 47, 40, 0, 83, 46, 73, 13, 12, 63, 15, 90, 121, 2, 69, 53, 28, 72, 97, 3, 4, 94, 106, 61, 96, 18, 80, 74, 44, 84, 107, 98, 93, 103, 5, 91, 32, 76, 20, 68, 81, 95, 29, 27, 86, 104, 7, 64, 113, 78, 105, 58, 118, 117, 50, 70, 10, 101, 110, 19, 1, 115, 102, 71, 79, 57, 77, 122, 48, 114, 54, 37, 59, 49, 100, 11, 14, 92, 16})

        duration := time.Since(start)

        fmt.Printf("Ballclock with %v balls took %s;\n", i, duration)
    }
}
```

This gave the output of:

```
Ballclock with 123 balls took 11.86748ms;
```

As you can see, the total time was 11.86 ms, all of which was spent in the `CalculateBallCycle` function. What would cause the benchmark to run in `456 ns/op` while the running program runs in around `11867480 ms/op`?

Comment: The first two test functions have nested for loops while the last one doesn't...

Comment: @dev.bmax that isn't an issue. The benchmark is done inside the `b.Run()` call.

Comment: @JRLambert Could you make a gist that would reproduce this issue ? Or tell us what's happening in `TickFive` so we can try and reproduce it ?

Comment: @yazgazan I added a link to the GitHub repo for the project

Comment: Experimenting quickly (without going too deep in your code), I tried a benchmark disabling `TickFive` and `CalculateBallCycle` in turns, and the performance issue only seem to arise when both are present. Glancing at your code, there seem to be a lot of side effects going on in your code, so finding the source of the "interference" will be tricky. (long story short, `TickFive` seems to worsen the performances of `CalculateBallCycle`).
I'll give it another try tomorrow, with a rested mind and no game of thrones to watch ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote that `CalcualteBallCycle()` modifies the slice by design.

I can't speak to correctness of that approach, but it is why benchmark time of `BenchmarkCalculateBallCycle123` is so different.

On first run it does the expected thing but on subsequent runs it does something completely different, because you're passing different data as input.

Benchmark this modified code:

```
func BenchmarkCalculateBallCycle123v2(b *testing.B) {
    m := []int{8, 62, 42, 87, 108, 35, 17, 6, 22, 75, 116, 112, 39, 119, 52, 60, 30, 88, 56, 36, 38, 26, 51, 31, 55, 120, 33, 99, 111, 24, 45, 21, 23, 34, 43, 41, 67, 65, 66, 85, 82, 89, 9, 25, 109, 47, 40, 0, 83, 46, 73, 13, 12, 63, 15, 90, 121, 2, 69, 53, 28, 72, 97, 3, 4, 94, 106, 61, 96, 18, 80, 74, 44, 84, 107, 98, 93, 103, 5, 91, 32, 76, 20, 68, 81, 95, 29, 27, 86, 104, 7, 64, 113, 78, 105, 58, 118, 117, 50, 70, 10, 101, 110, 19, 1, 115, 102, 71, 79, 57, 77, 122, 48, 114, 54, 37, 59, 49, 100, 11, 14, 92, 16}
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        tmp := append([]int{}, m...)
        CalculateBallCycle(tmp)
    }
}
```

This works-around this behavior by making a copy of m, so that `CalculateBallCycle` modifies a local copy.

The running time becomes more like the others:

```
BenchmarkCalculateBallCycle123-8         3000000           500 ns/op
BenchmarkCalculateBallCycle123v2-8           100      10483347 ns/op
```

Comment: *Face Palm*, thank you. I should have realized that was happening.

Answer (score 0):

In your `CycleClock` function, you are copying the `c.BallQueue` slice. You can improve performance significantly by using `CalculateBallCycle(c.BallQueue)` instead (assuming `CalculateBallCycle` doesn't modify the slice)

For example:

```
func Sum(values []int) int {
    sum := 0
    for _, v := range values {
        sum += v
    }

    return sum
}

func BenchmarkNoCopy(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        Sum(m)
    }
}

func BenchmarkWithCopy(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        Sum(append([]int{}, m...))
    }
}

// BenchmarkNoCopy-4        20000000            73.5 ns/op
// BenchmarkWithCopy-4       5000000           306 ns/op
// PASS
```

Comment: I made that change, and did improve it but not to the extent that I would hope. With the change, the bench mark is now `8930347 ns/op`, still roughly 1000x more than what I am hoping for.

Comment: Also, `CalculateBallCycle` will modify the slice, but that is the expected and wanted side effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a subtle bug in your tests.

Both methods `BenchmarkCycleClock` and `BenchmarkCycle24` run the benchmark in a for loop, passing a closure to `b.Run`. Inside of those closures you initialize the clocks using the loop variable `i` like this:`ballclock.NewClock(i)`.

The problem is, that all instances of your anonymous function share the same variable. And, by the time the function is run by the test runner, the loop will be finished, and all of the clocks will be initialized using the same value: `ballclock.MaxBalls`.

You can fix this using a local variable:

```
for i := ballclock.MinBalls; i <= ballclock.MaxBalls; i++ {
    i := i
    b.Run("BallCount="+strconv.Itoa(i), func(b *testing.B) {
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            c, _ := ballclock.NewClock(i)

            CycleClock(c)
        }
    })
}
```

The line `i := i` stores a copy of the current value of `i` (different for each instance of your anonymous function).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out but that is only an issue when using `testing.T` and calling `t.Parallel()` in the supplied `func`. `b.Run()` run sequentially so the value of `i` in the `func` passed to `b.Run()` is the correct value. Changing the benchmark to use a local variable did not affect the result of the benchmark. [Documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Subtests_and_Sub_benchmarks)